# std::multimap getting two ranges

Tags: c++, iterator, range, std, multimap

I'm using a C++ `std::multimap` and I have to loop over two different keys.  Is there an efficient way to do this other than creating two ranges and looping over those ranges seperately?

This is the way im doing it now:

```
std::pair<std::multimap<String, Object*>::iterator,std::multimap<String, Object*>::iterator> range;
std::pair<std::multimap<String, Object*>::iterator,std::multimap<String, Object*>::iterator> range2;

// get the range of String key
range = multimap.equal_range(key1);
range2 = multimap.equal_range(key2);

for (std::multimap<String, Object*>::iterator it = range.first; it != range.second; ++it)
{
    ...
}
for (std::multimap<String, Object*>::iterator it2 = range2.first; it2 != range2.second; ++it2)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: why do you think it's not efficient?

Comment: This is my first time using multimap's so I'm not too familiar with them.  I will be doing alot of work in those loops and I was wondering if there is another operation where you could get two ranges at the same time or something.

Comment: Can you give an example of keys where the keys overlap, but do not equal each other?  Maybe my brain is soggy, but it seems like a simple equality check on the keys would do it.  It makes more sense to me if you had separate lower and upper bounds for each query.

Comment: it's a great example when single `typedef` can eliminate bigger half of code and make code dramatically more readable: `typedef std::multimap<String, Object*>::iterator Iter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you started with is the most straightforward.

If you'd really like to iterate over two ranges in the same loop, you can create a custom iterator that takes two iterator ranges, iterates over the first until it's done then switches to the second. This is probably more trouble than it's worth, as you'd need to implement all of the iterator members yourself.

**Edit:** I was overthinking this; it's easy just to modify the two loops into a single one.

```
for (std::multimap<String, Object*>::iterator it = range.first; it != range2.second; ++it)
{
    if (it == range.second)
    {
        it = range2.first;
        if (it == range2.second)
            break;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I thought of this as well.  However, do these two keys have to be next to each other for this to work? For instance if I have 3 keys and I want to loop over the 1st and the 3rd wont it include the 2nd with them? Or do those if statements fix that?

Comment: @Kaiser, the `if` statements handle the transition from the first range to the second. They can even be out of order. The only thing they *can't* do is intersect; if `range2` includes `range.second` then you'll get an infinite loop.

Comment: Ahh I see. My range2 is static and range1 is always going to be different.  They should never intersect correct? Since multimap sorts it upon insertion?

Comment: @Kaiser, as long as the keys are different and you use `equal_range` as you did in your question, the ranges will not intersect. I also checked to make sure your `range2` iterators wouldn't be invalidated by insertion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules

Answer (score 3):

Boost does this, of course.  Using Boost.Range and its `join` function will get you what you want.  See [Boost Range Library: Traversing Two Ranges Sequentially](https://stackoverflow.com/q/152216/28817) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, Boost seems really powerful.  Unfortunately, my company is old school and hates new things...  I guess they'll have to settle for inefficiency

Comment: this time it's not about efficiency, it's about convenience

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to C++-11 (Visual Studio 10+, gcc-4.5+) and are allowed to use it `auto` is a real gem:

```
// get the range of String key
auto range = multimap.equal_range(key1);
auto range2 = multimap.equal_range(key2);

for (auto it = range.first; it != range.second; ++it)
{
    ...
}
for (auto it2 = range2.first; it2 != range2.second; ++it2)
{
    ...
}
```

Anyway, I would just test the keys and only do the second loop if key2 != key1.  Checking iterators each time in a loop has some cost.

A std::set_difference of the first range from the second might streamline the code.
Maybe std::set_union the two ranges and insert through back_inserter into a set so you only get one copy?

Some experiments may be in order.  Don't forget to put your first guess in the mix.  It might surprise you by being just fine in terms of speed.  Unless the ranges are typically very long and/or the loop operation is expensive it may not be worth the headache of extra bookkeeping.